# colname from pasted variable and character

Tags: r, paste, dplyr

I'm looking for a solution how to create new column name by pasting variable and character together.

In other words, the code below should create a new column with name "2018-12-27 started"

```
start_date <- paste(Sys.Date(), "started", sep = " ")
active_labels <- data %>%
      mutate(start_date = "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
start_date <- as.symbol(paste(Sys.Date(), "started", sep = " "))

active_labels <- data %>%
  mutate(!!start_date := 'hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to do outside of the tidyverse; use the `[[` accessor.

Set up example:

```
dd <- data.frame(x=1:3,y=4:6)
start_date <- paste(Sys.Date(), "started", sep = " ")
```

Assigning the column:

```
dd[[start_date]] <- "hello"
```